# My function aren't working after i called them

Tags: c

I've put an printf to check if the function works, but i cant figure out why it doesnt work.

The numbers are all correct in functions, but they dont get executed.

I am not sure why the function isn't working, i dont have much knowledge in C so if anyone could help me that would be much appreciated.

The program is supposed to calculate the odds of you passing the test, by calculating the odds of the people around in your class room.

Example:

```
  P
NXNXNXNXN
ZNZNXXXXX
XNZXNNNZX
ZNXHXXXXZ
NNNNZNNXN
```

`P - professor
Z - prepared student 
N - unprepared student
X - an empty seat
H - Me`

Input:

```
3 4
2 50
X X X X
Z H N X
Z N X X
```

Expected Output:

```
Sanse za prolaz su 62.50%
```

Output gotten:

```
Sanse za prolaz su -0.00
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


    ///FUNKCIJA POSTOTAK
float fudaljenost(int visina, int sirina,char array[visina][sirina])
{
    float postotak=0;
    float udaljenostx=0,udaljenosty=0,udaljenost=0;
    int Hx,Hy;
    int Zx,Zy;
    int Nx,Ny;

    for(int i=0;i<visina+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sirina;j++)
        {
             if(array[i][j]=='H')
             {
                Hx=i;
                Hy=j;
             }

        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<visina+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sirina;j++)
        {
             if(array[i][j]=='Z')
             {
                Zx=i;
                Zy=j;

                udaljenostx=abs(Hx-Zx);///A
                udaljenosty=abs(Hy-Zy);///B

                printf("Z A=%f B=%f\n",udaljenostx,udaljenosty);
                udaljenost=sqrt((udaljenostx*udaljenostx)+(udaljenosty*udaljenosty));///UDALJENOST

                postotak+=90/(udaljenost*udaljenost);///POSTOTAK
             }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<visina+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sirina;j++)
        {
             if(array[i][j]=='N')
             {
                Nx=i;
                Ny=j;

                udaljenostx=abs(Hx-Nx);///A
                udaljenosty=abs(Hy-Ny);///B
                printf("N A=%f B=%f\n",udaljenostx,udaljenosty);

                udaljenost=sqrt((udaljenostx*udaljenostx)+(udaljenosty*udaljenosty));///UDALJENOST

                postotak-=30/(udaljenost*udaljenost);///POSTOTAK
             }
        }
    }

    return postotak;
}

///FUNKCIJA PROFESOR
float fprofesor(float strogost,int visina, int sirina,char array[visina][sirina])
{
    float postotak=0;
    int Hx,Hy;
    int Px,Py;
    float udaljenostx=0,udaljenosty=0,udaljenost;

    for(int i=0;i<visina+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sirina;j++)
        {
             if(array[i][j]=='H')
             {
                Hx=i;
                Hy=j;
             }

        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<visina+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sirina;j++)
        {
             if(array[i][j]=='P')
             {
                Px=i;
                Py=j;

                udaljenostx=abs(Hx-Px);///A
                udaljenosty=abs(Hy-Py);///B

                udaljenost=sqrt((udaljenostx*udaljenostx)+(udaljenosty*udaljenosty));///UDALJENOST

                postotak=strogost/(udaljenost*udaljenost);///POSTOTAK
             }



        }
    }

    return postotak;
}
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    int visina,sirina;
    int prof;
    float strogost;
    float posto1,posto2,posto;
    char Ucionica[50][50]={0};


    float postotak=0;
    float udaljenostx=0,udaljenosty=0,udaljenost=0;
    int Hx,Hy;
    int Zx,Zy;
    int Nx,Ny;

    scanf(" %d%d",&visina,&sirina);
    scanf(" %d%f",&prof,&strogost);

    ///UPIS MATRICE
    for(i=1;i<visina+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sirina;j++)
        {
             scanf(" %c",&Ucionica[i][j]);
        }
    }
    Ucionica[0][prof-1]='P';

    posto1 = fudaljenost(visina,sirina,Ucionica);
    posto2 = fprofesor(strogost,visina,sirina,Ucionica);
    posto = posto1-posto2;

    printf("Sanse za prolaz su %.2f",posto);
    return 0;
}
```

Stackoverflow isnt allowing me to post this without adding more words, so im using this part of  the text to add more words, sorry stackoverflow for going around the system like this but im kinda running out of time on this.

Comment: Can you tell us more about desire output and output you got now?

Comment: the current outpout is -0.00

the input was 

3 4 new row
2 50 new row
X X X X new row
Z H N X new row
Z N X X

Expected output
```
Sanse za prolaz su 62.50%
```

Comment: please explain for what purpose did you create this code. It is hard to understand your code language

Comment: oh, sorry, im wasn't aware if the purpose was needed, as the variables when all in main without functions worked, but when i try to use functions and call them, they just dont work, im dont really understand functions so i might have done something wrong.

Comment: i added more info in the post

Comment: The math behind ods? How you calculate them?

Comment: We were given the formulas, it shouldn't be a problem.
The weird part is the functions arent doing anything when in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code passed cast on a main variable `char Ucionica[50][50]={0}` into a function that expects a prototype of `float fprofesor(float strogost,int visina, int sirina,char array[visina][sirina])`.

From the context, it looks as if the [50],[50[ represent the largest possible input size, but the program will use only the first few rows/columnns (3, 4 in the example). Regardless of how much data will be used, the definition in the called functions should match the data size.

```
float fprofesor(float strogost,int visina, int sirina,char array[50][50]) { ... }
float fudaljenost(int visina, int sirina,char array[50][50]) { ... }
```

Side note, `gcc -Wall` flaggedd many warning on unused variables, but no warning in passing array with mismatch minor array size

Also, probably a good idea to '#define' the maximum size, instead of hardcoding 50 repeated times.

Answer (score 0):

The functions were written wrong,

in

```
float fudaljenost(int visina, int sirina,char array[visina][sirina])
```

It wasn't the same size array as sent before[50][50]

The following will fix the problem:

```
float fudaljenost(int visina, int sirina,char array[50][50])
float fprofesor(float strogost,int visina, int sirina,char array[50][50])
```

Worth noting that it will be better to `#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 50`, and use MAX_ARRAY_SIZE instead of 50. This will make it easier to avoid error if the number will need to be changed, and will provide hint on what the 50 is.